# Activating Java Deployment Toolkit when working with applets

Tags: java, applet

I have java applet and it generates some data ( x,y,z) . I want to pass this data to JavaScript . But everytime i run the applet program, browser doesn't allow me to run that program. I tried in mozilla, IE, Google Chrome etc and all of them are updated.

It says "Activate Java Deployment Toolkit " but which we cannot activateon our browser. It has got no option for activation.

Please tell me what's going on here.

Comment: here the javascript is used for web application...

Comment: This happens because your browser is [blocking the Deployment Toolkit Plugin](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8022835?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel) (see comments on that "issue"). You'll have to configure it to not block it. See also the [Deployment Toolkit FAQ](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/deployment_toolkit.xml) and ["applet activate java deployment toolkit"](https://www.google.com/search?q=applet+activate+java+deployment+toolkit), which is the quick cursory Google search that led me to that information in the first place.

Comment: @ Jason , Thank you a nd I will have look at this..